# How to push my c++ project with boost dependency libraries and headers

Tags: c++, git, github, boost, msbuild

[image]

I use Visual Studio 2019 as ide.
I add Boost 1_78_0 version to my project.
When i push my code to github, it pushed without dependencies. I search a lot but cannot find anything, Picture that below shows you that if i cloned my code from github, that errors occurs. How can i push with configuration and boost dependencies.

Comment: I recommend having your project tell the developer its dependencies, rather than pushing those dependencies into the project itself.  (Unless your project is, itself, a fork of Boost.)

Comment: in github you should provide a 'recipe' for your dependencies (instead of dependencies themselves).
if your project is VS only - you can use vcpkg for managing your dependencies. if you use cmake - it can be conan, vcpkg or cmake itself

Comment: Did you add Boost as a submodule? If so, you want to add to `git clone --recurse-submodules git://url...`